# Edit excel file in node server using WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, teamcity, selenium-grid, selenium-rc

I have a TeamCity server (which in my case Selenium Hub as well) which triggers my Selenium-Python testcases and runs it in another windows server (node).

Following is the typical test case i want to achieve in selenium hub-node configuration.

1. Click 'Download Template' in app, that downloads an excel workbook
2. Get the file path of the latest downloaded file in Chrome/Downloads (I get this working using the code snippet below)
3. Pass this file path to excel writer library, which in turn populate some data
4. Go back to app, click on 'Upload Template' which opens up a file upload window, and I use autoit script to pass the file path to this window and proceed with further steps

**Code to get the latest downloaded file in node server**:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def get_file_names_chrome():
  if not driver.current_url.startswith("chrome://downloads"):
    driver.get("chrome://downloads/")
  return driver.execute_script("""
          return downloads.Manager.get().items_
          .filter(e => e.state === "COMPLETE")
          .map(e => e.file_url);
          """)


try:
    files = get_file_names_chrome()
    print (files)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

As of now, my TeamCity build step, deploys the automation source code in node server and uses powershell to trigger these testcases from hub server. However I want the Selenium Hub to handle my cases and distribute it.

Is there any other way I can achieve these?

Comment: Hello, Shan! Can you give more details about the team city process. It just trigger the hub to start an instance on a node or it deploy/build/run the test on the node?

Comment: Sure @Infern0 As of now, I am deploying the automation source code in node server and triggering the testcases using windows task scheduler. So temacity build step just calls this windows task schedule right after deploying the code.